# Apache mod rewrite .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I can get basic tests to work with mod rewrite ie:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php$ test.php
```

But what I'm really trying to accomplish is changing my dynamic url ie:

```
detail.php?id=1
```

to something like

```
detail-id-18.htm
```

Now this is what I have in place (that I thought would have worked) but of course nothing is happening:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule detail-id-(.*)\.htm$ detail.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Do you need the carrot in front of the detail-id... rewrite?

Comment: @Micah, tried that will no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^detail-id-([0-9]+)\.htm$ detail.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Please show me an example URL that you are trying. And you are entering this in your .htaccess with +AllowOveride set in your http config right? If you aren't, add it and restart your apache service.

Comment: And Layke are you referring to the Allow in the httpd.conf? If so, I did set that

Comment: Correctly, sorry that returns "The requested URL /detail-id-15.html was not found on this server.

Comment: @Starboy --  modify the rule from @Layke answer a bit -- change `htm` to `html` ... or try accessing `/detail-id-15.htm` instead (notice slightly different file extension -- only 3 chars compared to yours 4).